# Cycle through a list to do Find & Replace

Tags: shell, sed, applescript, repeat, automator

In my script theString is typically less than 200 words.
theFindList and replaceWithList have 78 terms in each... to find every occurrence of each term from the first list and replace it with the corresponding term in the second list.
Script runs fine, but it's slow to do the sed command in 78 different do shell script calls in a repeat loop.
It would be faster if the everything was passed to the shell for the iterations to be done there. How do I do that?
Here's the relevant repeat portion of what is now in applescript. I'll be putting the thing into Automator, so something I can do in a "run shell script" action would work. I could have the find and replace lists in a string of tab delimited data. The find and replace lists are constant, so need those baked into the shell script and only needs to receive theString from the previous action.

```
set theString to "foo 1.0 is better than foo 2.0. The fee 5 is the best."
set toFindList to {"foo", "fee", "fo", "fum"}
set replaceWith to {"bar", "bee", "bo", "bum"}
set cf to count of toFindList
-- replace each occurrence of the word followed by a space and a digit
repeat with n from 1 to cf
    set toFindThis to item n of toFindList
    set replaceWithThis to item n of replaceWithList
    set scriptText to "echo " & quoted form of theString & " | sed -e 's/" & toFindThis & " \\([0-9]\\)/" & replaceWithThis & " \\1/'g"
    set theString to do shell script scriptText
end repeat
return theString
```

Comment: If it is OK to bake the search and replace strings into the shell script, would it also be OK to do them in a single sed script? That would get rid of the loop and a lot of starting and closing execution contexts. If it is OK, then write to "fumbum.sed" several lines of `s/foo/bar/g;s/fee/bee/g; s/fo/bo/g...` and call `sed -f fumbum.sed`.

Comment: Can you make a command file with lines like `s/foo\( [0-9])/bar\1/g ` and use `sed -f commandfile` ?

Comment: @WalterA Good point, I forgot the ` \\([0-9]\\)`.

Comment: Yes, I could write the lists to a tmp file. I've never used sed with a command file. btw, I don't have to use sed, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, using the sed -f commandfile technique, I got it working. The script takes a tab delimited string or file, then builds a sed command file from that.

```
property theString: "foo 1.0 is better than foo 2.0. The fee 5 is the best."
property substitutionList : "foo    bar
fee bee
fo  bo
bum bum" -- this tab delim list will have 78 terms

set tabReplace to "\\( [0-9]\\)/"
set paragraphReplace to "\\1/g
s/"

-- parse the replace string into lists
set commandString to ""
set otid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab
set commandString to text items of substitutionList
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tabReplace
set commandString to "s/" & commandString as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set commandString to text items of commandString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to paragraphReplace
set commandString to (commandString as string) & "\\1/g"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid

set commandFilePath to ((path to temporary items from user domain) as text) & "commandFile.sed"
try
    set fileRef to open for access file commandFilePath with write permission
    set eof of fileRef to 0
    write commandString to fileRef
    close access fileRef
on error
    close access fileRef
end try
set posixPath to POSIX path of file commandFilePath

set scriptText to "echo " & quoted form of theString & " | sed -f " & quoted form of posixPath
set theString to do shell script scriptText
return theString
```